# C++ access violation when writing to typdef struct

Tags: c++

I have a struct defined in a header file.  Then I have a singleton class where I am trying to use the struct.  When I call ResetVars() from another class I get an access violation when it hits the line that says test.numResponses = "TEST".  I am assuming this has something to do with initialization but I haven't been able to solve it. I am new to c++ and I have no idea how to get around this.  Thanks for any help.

struct.h

```
typedef  struct POLL_DATA
{
    std::string numResponses;
    std::string type;
    std::string question;   
} POLL_DATA;
```

ControlPolls.h

```
class ControlPolls

{
    private:
        static bool instanceFlag;
        static ControlExitPolls *controlSingle;
        ControlExitPolls();

        POLL_DATA test;
    public:

        static ControlExitPolls* getInstance();
        void ResetVars();
};
```

ControlPolls.cpp

```
#include "ControlPolls.h"

bool ControlPolls::instanceFlag = false;
ControlPolls* ControlPolls::controlSingle = NULL;

//Private Constructor
ControlExitPolls::ControlExitPolls()
{
};

//Get instance
ControlPolls* ControlPolls::getInstance()

{
    if(!instanceFlag)

    {
        controlSingle =  &ControlPolls();
        instanceFlag = true;
        return controlSingle;
    }

    else

    {
        return controlSingle;
    }
}

void ControlExitPolls::ResetVars()
{

        test.numResponses = "TEST";
}
```

callingClass.cpp

```
ControlPolls *controlSingleton;
controlSingleton = ControlPolls::getInstance();
controlSingleton->getInstance()->ResetVars();
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: Why do you need `typedef struct` in c++ in the first place?

Comment: class A.h includes struct.h

Comment: whats the better way to hold the data in the struct?

Comment: `POLL_DATA testPoll();` declares a function. It does **not** initialize the `testPoll` member of `a`.

Comment: `struct Foobar { .. };` is sufficient in c++ to use `Foobar` as data type without `struct`. Also note uppercase identifiers are usually used for preprocessor macro so it is a good idea to avoid using them for other purpose.

Comment: _@user3137612_ To repeat @slava's request: Post a [MCVE] please!

Answer (score 2):

You've been struck by C++'s *Most Vexing Parse*, a compiler rule that says anything that could be a function declaration *is* a function declaration. The culprit is this line:

```
POLL_DATA testPoll();
```

testPoll is treated as the declaration of a function with return type `POLL_DATA`. Try removing the brackets, or writing simply `POLL_DATA testPoll;` which implicitly calls the compiler-generated default constructor.
Another **larger** problem is that `testPoll` is a member of `A`, but you've hidden it and declared a local variable in your constructor, `A::A()`. I suggest you remove the constructor altogether because the implicit constructor will suffice.

Some more notes on your code:

- You've declared your class `a` but refer to it later as `A`.
- You've written an implementation of a constructor for `A` without declaring it like a proper forward declaration.

Also, `typedef struct` is not needed in C++. It is sufficient and encouraged to write:

```
struct POLLDATA {
    ...
};
```

Comment: Since `POLL_DATA` has a default constructor (generated by the compiler) there is no need to explicitly initialize it in the ctor initializer list or the body of the constructor. `POLL_DATA testPoll = POLL_DATA().` is going to create a local and has no affect on the instantiation of the members of the object. Also I see no indication that this fixes the problem vaguely referred to by the OP.  So how does this fix the error that the OP didn't bother to include?

Comment: Edited as per your comment (which is obvious, my pardon) and made note of other errors.

Comment: @TimStraubinger Well, it looks it's even worse. Would `POLL_DATA testPoll;` even make any sense??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have placed emphasis, thank you

Comment: This still does not answer the question about why they are getting an error with the assignment. You're addressing issues in the constructor which are not likely to be the source of the problem since the OP even calls it out in `ResetVars`.This is why you don't answer questions that are missing extremely important details about the problem including the missing [mcve]. Good try but it doesn't address the actual problem.